# Android: release version failed due to inability to compute hash?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard, release

I don't really understand what I need to do in order to make it so that proguard can reduce the size of the apk. The app I am releasing is using the Google Maps API v2 and so far, it works okay except for the fact that this message appears when I try to generate a signed APK.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> Unable to compute hash of (app path)\app\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar
```

How do I fix this issue?

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abcd.efgh"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
}
```

proguard-project.txt

```
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself.

First, I went to the gradle and made sure that in this part in the gradle,

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
```

the second file name was the same name as the proguard file.

Then, I added these things to the top of the proguard file:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

That in the end caused proguard to succesfully create a release version.